# Rendering lights in JavaScript so slow. Any idea?

Tags: javascript, canvas, rendering, frame-rate, light

I have a light-rendering method written in JavaScript, which can set the brightness of each object. If I call rendering objects with this filter in the main loop, it'll be very slow (8-10 fps). Is it too much for JavaScript, or just an unoptimized solution?

If I call it outside of the main loop then it's OK.

Here is the `Animator` class, which has that method I wrote about. You should call the `renderImage` method with the `brightness` switch.

```
Animator: { // Animator class 
  renderImage: function(ImageObject,imageX,imageY,filterData = []) {
  /*
    filterData [] =
    0 -> type
    1 -> value for filtering
  */
  switch( filterData[0] )
  {
    case 'none':
      engComponents.ctx.drawImage(ImageObject,imageX,imageY);
      break;

    case 'brightness':
      engComponents.ctx.drawImage(ImageObject,imageX,imageY);
      pixels = engComponents.ctx.getImageData(imageX,imageY,imageX+50,imageY+50);
      data = pixels.data;
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i+=4) {
        data[i] += filterData[1];
        data[i+1] += filterData[1];
        data[i+2] += filterData[1];
      }
      engComponents.ctx.putImageData(pixels,imageX,imageY);
      break;
  }
```

Thank you for any helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get/putImageData are fairly slow operations. If you in addition need to do this for each object, then expecting real-time performance update is perhaps a little too much to hope for. It's fully possible to do with compiled code and direct access to a display card, but with JavaScript and canvas including all the fail safes it comes with, we are forced to dwell in trickery.

One thing you could (probably should) do is to cache variants of the images/objects in question before the game starts. Define some key brightness values and generate a sprite-sheet of those. Then use an index for brightness instead of actual brightness, so you simply draw the cell with the intended brightness to screen instead of calculating during each frame.

Lets take this guy for instance:

[image: Imgur]

Now generate a sprite sheet with various brightness values - do this in Photoshop or dynamically in the code (latter shown in demo below):

[image: sprite]

```js
var sctx = document.getElementById("sprite").getContext("2d"),
    ctx = document.getElementById("main").getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image;
    
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.onload = genSprite;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHgNx.png";  // 106x120

function genSprite() {

  sctx.canvas.width = 5 * this.width;          // set sprite size: image width x cells
  sctx.canvas.height = this.width;
  sctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);                  // draw in image to brighten
  
  
  // generate some brightness cells
  var bStep = 25,                              // brightness step per cell
      max = 5,                                 // max sprites
      idata = sctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height), // get once only
      data = idata.data,                       
      len = data.length;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {               // iterate to increase values
    for(var p = 0; p < len; p++) {
      data[p++] += bStep;
      data[p++] += bStep;
      data[p++] += bStep;
    }
    sctx.putImageData(idata, this.width * i, 0); // update at cell pos. with new values
  }
  
  // now we have our sprite-sheet, release the Kraken!
  game();
}

/*==========================================================
This part is just to demonstrate you can draw many instances
with varying brightness without suffer from low frame-rate
==========================================================*/

function game() {

  var dudes = [], // holds Dude objects
      max = 70,   // num. of dudes
      i = 0;
  
  // create game dudes
  while(i++ < max) dudes.push(new Dude(sctx.canvas, ctx));
  
  // animate
  (function loop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    var i = 0;
    while(dude = dudes[i++]) dude.update();  // update dude
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  })();
  
}

function Dude(sprite, ctx) {
  var b = (4 * Math.random())|0,   // brightness index (fractional is ok)
      db = 0.25,                   // step for brightness, we round it to integer later
      w = ctx.canvas.width,        // cache some values
      h = ctx.canvas.height,
      x = w * 0.5,                 // center of canvas
      y = h * 0.5,
      v = 1 + 4 * Math.random(),   // random velocity
      a = Math.PI*2*Math.random(), // random angle
      dx = Math.cos(a) * v,        // steps based on angle
      dy = Math.sin(a) * v;
  
  // updates position and brightness cell
  this.update = function() {
    
    // position:
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if (x < -106 || x > w || y < -120 || y > h) {
      x = w * 0.5;
      y = h * 0.5;
    }
    
    // brightness:
    b += db;
    if (b <= 0 || b >= 4) db = -db;

    // clip the cell from sprite-sheet and draw to main canvas
    // Note the 106*(b|0) - (b|0) will force integer number which we need.
    ctx.drawImage(sprite, 106*(b|0), 0, 102, sprite.height,  x, y, 106, sprite.height);
  };
}
```

```css
#sprite {border:1px solid #000;margin-bottom:4px;}
```

```html
<canvas id="sprite"></canvas><br>
<canvas id="main" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help!

So to clarify. Load sprites, make variatons, and cache the imageData of each variation, and just use the imageData to render?

Comment: @LászlóLukács no problem. And almost, except last step, just use the new sprite canvas as an image for drawImage() (no need to use ImageData from getImageData after that).

Comment: I did it, but I have one more problem. When I open the code in firefox at the first time its okay. But when I press ctrl+f5 it doesn't show the brightened pictures. Internet Explorer shows just some of the pictures, and Chrome doesn't show anything except for when i press enter on the link. I'm using a plugin which preloads sprites called pxLoader but doesn't help. What would u recommend ?

Comment: @LászlóLukács well, see if my [YAIL](https://github.com/epistemex/yail) loader can help with the image loading (try f.ex. the LT/light version) :-)

Comment: Okay ill see, What do you think, is It a result of unloadad sprites?

Comment: @LászlóLukács it is likely a problem with handling the async load behavior (ie, not properly handling onload etc. - there could also be errors that needs to be handled using onerror/onabort).

Comment: I solved, Im using setTimeout on the cycle which loads sprites with different brightness.